# Is there a name for a equivalence that one proposition is a special case of the other?

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

Sometimes two theorems are equivalents but one of them is actually a special case of the other. For instance,

1. and Rolle's Theorem and Mean Value Theorem
2. Pythagorean theorem and Law of cosines

Since one is a special case of the other, one direction of implication is imediate. The interesting is the opposite direction. I would like to know if there is a classification for this kind of situation.

Comment: I don’t think the word “equivalence” is used correctly here. Are you looking for the word “generalization” (the opposite of “special case”)?

Comment: Are you familiar with first order logic? I *think* I understand what you’re asking for, but it’ll be easier for me to explain if you know FOL.

Comment: I don't know. Do you have a reference?

Comment: For example, the ideas discussed on this Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: I'm familiar with sentences depending on variables and using quantifier like $\forall$ and $\exists$. But I didn't know it is called first order logic.

Comment: Are you looking for the term [corollary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corollary)?

Comment: No. I want to know if there is a special name for this kind of equivalence. Or better, for the case in that the spacial case implies the general.

Comment: If the **corollary** turns out to imply the original theorem—in other words, if the corollary turns out to *not* be a special case after all—then the corollary and original theorem are **equivalent** to each other.